# Get the current directory name via php script in another directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm working on styling apache indexes via a header.php file included from an .htaccess file. I've got it to a good point, but I need to retrieve the current page title from the URL. All the php references point me to solutions that work for getting the "current page" which is the included php file itself, and not the directory in which it's indexing.

Using this works, but brings up the header.php:

```
$current_folder = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Thoughts on how to pull this off?

Edit: Folder structure is like this, if it helps to make more sense:

```
/
    /includes/header.php
    /dir/directory_that_I_want_the_name_of/
```

The .htaccess pulls in header.php for each directory index, so I need to know how to get the current directory name, not where the header.php lives, which comes back with /includes/ or header.php in the examples that I've found. I need to be fetching directory_that_I_want_the_name_of.

.htaccess:

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
IndexOptions FoldersFirst IgnoreCase XHTML NameWidth=*
IndexOptions SuppressHTMLPreamble SuppressRules HTMLTable
IndexOptions IconHeight=16 IconWidth=16
IndexOptions SuppressDescription

HeaderName includes/header.php
ReadmeName includes/footer.html
```

Comment: i'm confused, You want to get the path of the current page?

Comment: not sure I completely understand your question, but did you try `__DIR__`?

Comment: Can you post your `.htaccess` code?

Comment: Posted .htaccess and a bit of clairification. @anubhava

Comment: Thanks, now tell me what is your full URL and are you trying to get `directory_that_I_want_the_name_of` from inside `header.php`?

Comment: For conversations sake: /var/www/domain.com/dir/ @anubhava

Comment: BUT, it needs to work on all directories, not just /dir

Comment: No I wanted the full URL that you're entering in your browser and secondly are you trying to get directory_that_I_want_the_name_of from inside header.php?

Comment: I think that you're making it harder than it needs to be. Let's say we're going to domain.com/dir. .htaccess pulls in the header.php file that does all of the processing. Problem is, header.php lives in domain.com/includes/header.php, so when you query the script for the directory name, it thinks that it's in domain.com/includes/ instead of domain.com/dir. I need it to pull the directory name and print it out for domain.com/dir, domain.com/dir2, domain.com/dir3, etc. Does that make sense? @anubhava

Comment: It makes total sense now can as per my understanding php cannot be included in `HeaderName` directive with above code you have shown. Are you sure php code in `header.php` is getting executed? On my apache it is only allowing html code in `HeaderName` directive so I am unable to test it.

Comment: @anubhava Yes. It gets executed in my environment just fine with PHP5. The whole script is based on it and works great, other than the title function, which I'm trying to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recreated all of this setup and was able to get base dir-name using:

```
echo basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

in **`/includes/header.php`**.

Make sure to have your .htaccess code like this:

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
IndexOptions FoldersFirst IgnoreCase XHTML NameWidth=*
IndexOptions SuppressHTMLPreamble SuppressRules HTMLTable
IndexOptions IconHeight=16 IconWidth=16
IndexOptions SuppressDescription

AddType text/html .php
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .php

HeaderName /includes/header.php
ReadmeName /includes/footer.html
```

Comment: It's close, but it will pull in the directory, plus any directory above it. Say you're in domain.com/dir/dir2, it will print /dir/dir2. I need it to print "Dir2".

Comment: Hah. That was a lot of explaining for a simple fix. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I learnt few new tricks today. +1 to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of your questions, but it sounds like you are looking for the URL/Directory of the page you are currently on, not the directory of the header?

What about:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Those all give info about the current file open by the server based on the HTTP request it received.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to get the directory name of the current directory, not where the php page that generates the header lives. That said, all of your examples generate paths based off the the header.php file that I'm trying to get away from.